# How to work with symbols, numbers, and letters in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, vectorization

I'm working on my first Tensorflow model and when I was training the dataset, my accuracy dropped to 25% from around 60% when using sci-kit. A friend told me it might have to do with some of the data, for example, "781C376B-E380-C052-448B-B4AB6F3D". How do I deal with symbols (dashes here), numbers, and letters in my data when running my models?

Currently I am looking into text vectorization so it could read my data easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can you tf.strings.unicode_decode() which converts an encoded string scalar to a vector of code points. It provides unique number for each character in the string.

For example:

```
# A batch of Unicode strings, each represented as a UTF8-encoded string.

batch_utf8 = [s.encode('UTF-8') for s in
              [u'781C376B-E380-C052-448B-B4AB6F3D']]
batch_chars_ragged = tf.strings.unicode_decode(batch_utf8,
                                               input_encoding='UTF-8')
for sentence_chars in batch_chars_ragged.to_list():
  print(sentence_chars)

output:[55, 56, 49, 67, 51, 55, 54, 66, 45, 69, 51, 56, 48, 45, 67, 48, 53, 50, 45, 52, 52, 56, 66, 45, 66, 52, 65, 66, 54, 70, 51, 68]
```

For more details please refer to this [document](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/guide/unicode). Thank You.

Comment: I appreciate your response, thank you!